# Why is paredit not working void function enable-paredit-mode

Tags: emacs, clojure

Im trying to get paredit to work in Emacs but i can't even find it when I type M-x paredit* nothing comes up about paredit.

When I use `(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook #'enable-paredit-mode)` emacs tells me void function.

What is the problem, as i understand it paredit ships with emacs and no additional install is needed.

Comment: As far as I know, paredit dos *not* ship with Emacs. If your Emacs is relatively new, the easiest way to install it is to use `package.el` and MELPA, MELPA-stable (highly recommended), or Marmalade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `(require 'paredit)` somewhere in your init file before you can `(enable-paredit-mode)`.  Alternately, `paredit` is autoloaded: you could also use `(paredit-mode)` (which should be available even without the `require`) which will load everything else. ... aaand actually, `enable-paredit-mode` is also an autoloaded function, so that should have worked.  Are you sure you've got the package installed?

Comment: how can i know what i need to require?

Comment: Got it working but changed over to smartparens instead